# Galaxy tablet requires restart to download attachments

Tags: gmail, downloading, samsung-galaxy-tab, attachments

I have a Galaxy Tab A (SM-T550) running Android 5.0.2 that only downloads files from emails (in Gmail) if I restart it — after I have downloaded a file, I have to restart it for a second download. Our email is visa bt internet and if I click on a document or picture to download the progress bar runs, but it stays on 0% unless I restart the tablet.